# themes.xml does not affect to my ActionBar for different Android Versions

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I would like to customize my ActionBar using themes.xml. For this purpose I use the following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="MyCustomStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyCustomStyle.ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomStyle.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyCustomStyle.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="background">@color/Green</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomStyle.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Red</item>
    </style>  
</resources>
```

I set it as my activity's theme on my Manifest.

When I try it with a device with 2.2.1, it works. However, when I try 4.1.2 and 4.2.x, 4.3  , I see the default Gray background and black title color and the following line on my LogCat :

```
04-10 17:38:07.296: W/ResourceType(11830): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0 (error -75)
```

Could you please point my mistake ?

Comment: see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground). Esp. at part for 3.0 and higher. This is what you need to ad. I think you currently only set style for support-AB.

Comment: but I use min sdk 8. I cant apply "<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>"

Comment: You have to! One assignment is for old API and one for newer API. But that's not where the error comes from. I think it is not allowed to provide a color as background in ActionBarStyle. (this part: `<item name="background">@color/Green</item>`). You have to wrap it in a drawable (e.g. a rectangle drawable with color green as solid)

Comment: it should have throw an error in that case or kind of warning should have been appeared I think. Is it possible the reason is that line : xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating new themes.xml and style.xml in values-v11 and values-v14 folders by adding extra "android:actionBarStyle", "android:titleTextStyle" and "android:background" attributes. Although the min sdk value is 8 in my project, "android:" key can be used and works in values-v11 and values-v14 folders.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyCustomStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyCustomStyle.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyCustomStyle.ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomStyle.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyCustomStyle.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>

        <item name="android:background">@color/ichaseutheme</item>
        <item name="background">@color/Red</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomStyle.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Green</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```